# Creating factories for has_many and belongs_to where validation is set on both sides of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following setup in my codebase. In such a case what would be the correct way to specify the factories so that we get to keep validation on both the models.

**Models:**

```
class LabTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lab_test_fields
  validates_presence_of :lab_test_fields
end

class LabTestField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lab_test
  validates_presence_of :lab_test
end
```

**Factories:**

```
factory :lab_test do
  lab_test_fields FactoryGirl.build_list(:lab_test_field, 5)
end

factory :lab_test_field do
  lab_test
end
```

With this setup if I try to create `lab_test` or `lab_test_field` factory by doing `FactoryGirl.create(:lab_test)` or `FactoryGirl.create(:lab_test_field)`, I get `Trait not registered: lab_test (ArgumentError)` which is quite unexpected.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see, you have a typo in the factory. This line...

`lab_test_fields FactoryGirl.build_list(:lab_test_field, 5)`

...is missing an "=" sign.

So it *should* be:

`lab_test_fields = FactoryGirl.build_list(:lab_test_field, 5)`.

Also, if you're trying to create 5 `lab_test_fields`, you want to use `create_list` not `build_list`. Create will give you a persisted object, while build gives you an object that isn't persisted. Anyway, that missing "=" sign sounds like its why you're getting that error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not the case, please check  `factory_girl` syntax - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: Also `build` would not give hash of attributes, for attributes `factory_girl` provides `attributes_for`.

Comment: Which part is not the case? The "=" sign or the `create_list` vs `build_list`? The link you sent me shows them using `create_list` without storing it anywhere, so they don't use an "=" sign. They just create 3 admin users. If that's what you want to do, then you need to do `create_list(:lab_test_field, 5)` instead of `lab_test_fields FactoryGirl.build_list(:lab_test_field, 5)`.

Comment: I'm going off this documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Building_or_Creating_Multiple_Records
You're right about the `build_list` vs `create_list`. I worded, that wrong. I'll fix it.

Comment: missing "=" sign is not the case because I don't get a Syntax error.

Comment: You know, every use for `build_list` and `create_list` I'm seeing is outside of a factory definition. I'm starting to wonder if you can even use it within a factory definition the way you want to do it. Have you tried doing something like `5.times do build(:lab_test_field) end`?